# Data not being displayed in Angular despite Cross Origin Support (Angular + Spring)

Tags: angular, spring, typescript

I am trying to build a full stack application using Spring and Angular.

I have successfully configured my REST APIs and they are working fine on port 8080.
However, when I try to access them via my frontend (Angular service), the page loads perfectly but no data is displayed. I have added the cross origin support to my interface in Spring, so no errors are shown in the console window as well.

However, it shows that the data retrieved is undefined. (pictures attached)

**Customer-List Component (typescript)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Customer } from 'src/app/common/customer';
import { CustomerService } from 'src/app/services/customer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-list',
  templateUrl: './customer-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-list.component.css']
})
export class CustomerListComponent implements OnInit {

  customers: Customer[];

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.listCustomers();
  }

  listCustomers() {
    this.customerService.getCustomerList().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.customers = data;
        console.log(`Data retrieved: ${this.customers}`);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Customer Component (html)**

```
<p>
    this works!
</p>

<p *ngFor = "let tempCust of customers">
    hello
    {{ tempCust.name }}
</p>
```

**Customer Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Customer } from '../common/customer';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CustomerService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/customerDetails';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getCustomerList(): Observable<Customer[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<GetResponse>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
      map(response => response._embedded.customers)
    )
  }
}

interface GetResponse{
  _embedded : {
    customers: Customer[];
  }
}
```

**Port 4200**
[Image for page shown on port 4200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnGxj.png)

**Port 8080**
[Image for page shown on Port 8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZLWK.png)

Where am I possibly going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your API is putting the data in `response._embedded.customerDetails`, not `response._embedded.customers`

Comment: How can this be fixed?

I believed that
map(response => response._embedded.customers)
maps the response received onto the array of types Customers that I have created.

Answer (score 0):

Check get and post request for your api in browser developer tools and be sure to angular gets the response. if any successful response get from api, your problem could be an object mapping issue such filed name.